# Connect Spring Boot to multiple Artemis brokers

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-artemis

How can I call multiple ActiveMQ Artemis brokers in Spring Boot? Only `spring.artemis.host` and `spring.artemis.port` are documented in [Common Application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#common-application-properties). With these two parameters, only one broker can be referenced. I'm looking for something like `spring.artemis.url` mentioned [in this Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10739).

Comment: What exactly is your use-case?

Comment: I have a symmetric cluster (non HA) of at least two AMQ Artemis brokers. My spring-boot application configures this as its URL `spring.artemis.broker-url=(tcp://broker1:port1,tcp://broker2:port2)?ha=false` but all messages are handled only by the broker1. In case the broker1 is shut down, the broker2 takes action. I would like that both brokers work as they form a cluster and the `message-load-balancing` is `ON_DEMAND`

Comment: So you're already using a URL? If so, I'm not clear on why you referenced the Spring Boot issue requesting URL support.

Comment: How many clients do you have connecting to your cluster? With `ON_DEMAND` `message-load-balancing` the brokers will prefer local clients so if you have a cluster of 2 brokers and consumers are on both brokers then messages sent to one broker will stay there to feed the consumers on that broker.

Comment: As my client requests just stay on the broker1, I thought there must be something wrong with the URL. After having verified the documentation, I see that no `spring.artemis.url` is available. That's why I wonder whether AMQ Artemis can be used in springboot client for production. During my tests, I launched a five publisher clients and 2 subscriptions. They all connect to the broker1. What should be done in order that both brokers will serve my client requests?